# Using pandas module to assign an excel cell value to a variable [Python 3.8, Linux]

Tags: python, excel, pandas

**Foreword:**

I'd prefer to avoid lengthy processes if possible. As a beginner, one line with lots of syntax is a little overwhelming, if I need to use something similar, please give a basic note on what they do. It's not vital that I know, it just takes the edge off. Please, point out where I'm using inefficient code and suggest better functions and/or modules, as I said I have little knowledge in python.

**Situation:**

I'm a newbie to pandas, but I've taken the time to play around with `x.iloc[y,x]` and `x.loc[y,x]` (where x is `pd.read_excel('/my/file/name.xlsx', sheet_name='sheet1')`)and, at least for the given formats, I understand what makes them tick. I know that these are going to be useful to me for my macros. I'm on Linux so VBA isn't an easy option, and PyUNO for LibreOffice is a project I'm putting off for a while. I'm expecting that the above functions aren't the best way to select a cell in excel from python.

**What I've found:**

Too much. For a beginner like me, most of the tutorials are very complex with little explanation; I can make the code there work, I just have no clue why it works that way. I've mostly found information relating to standard 'in-house' python databases, and it seems that the excel related articles are few and far between, the ones I've read unfortunately relate to more advanced functions. I could probably learn them, but I'm not currently interested.

**The issue:**

Lets take a look at this code I wrote earlier, with a little help from pythonbasics.org;

```
import pandas as pd
import xlrd #not sure if this is needed, thonny assistant says its not, website says it is
df = pd.read_excel('/home/myname/Desktop/sheetname.xlsx', sheet_name='sheet1')
p = df.loc[5, 5]
p = str(p) #unsure if this does anything, I haven't got a write to A.txt either way
path = "/home/mynmae/Desktop/A.txt"
text_file = open(path, "w")
text_file.write('%s' % p)
text_file.close
```

Lets get rid of the mess.
First, I read sheetname.xlsx and assign it to df

```
df = pd.read_excel('/home/myname/Desktop/sheetname.xlsx', sheet_name='sheet1')
```

Now I try reading cell F6, lets keep in the string conversion for p

```
p = df.loc[5, 5]
p = str(p)
```

now that we've got p, lets open up a text file on my desktop

```
path = "/home/mynmae/Desktop/A.txt"
text_file = open(path, "w")
```

All that's left is to 'paste' p into the text file. We opened it with 'w' so we can write over the file. p is a string, so we write with `('%s' % p)`

```
text_file.write('%s' % p)
text_file.close
```

Now we should have the value of F6 (lets say its "hello") in A.txt! Lets see:

```
A.txt;
```

..Oh

**What I know:**

All the write stuff works in a second program I have. The only difference is `p` is replaced by another string variable, I would guess that isn't the issue. However, when I call `print(p)` after converting `p = str(p)` it gives me what I want, with the headers in place. I would like to remove the headers but that's for later.

**My question:**

given spreadsheet 'sheetname.xlsx' and worksheet 'sheet1', using pandas (or a better module for spreadsheet work if there is one) how can I assign the value of cell F6 (or any cell, switching up my selection is easy) to the variable `p`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it without Pandas, using module [xlrd](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```
import xlrd

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('sheetname.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('sheet1')

# Read specific cell and store it in variable:
value = worksheet.cell(row, column)

# row and column are indexed as Python does, so cell 'A1' is (0,0)
```

Comment: I can't believe how easy that is! Seems excactly the same as VBA's Range("LetterNumber") function. I'll read up on xlrd and get my system up and running. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**Solution to your problem:**

You're going to be livid at how silly the fix is. You forgot to put `()` after `text_file.close`. You're not executing the `.close()` function. It isn't throwing a runtime error because it's just returning the value of the `.close` function in that line. It is then moving onto the following lines of code.

Please try this:

```
path = "/home/myname/Desktop/A.txt"
text_file = open(path, "w")
text_file.write('%s' % p)
text_file.close()
```

---

**Additional:**

- For the functionality you're using, you must have the `xlrd` module installed in your environment, but it doesn't need to be imported.
- If you want to use integer indices freely on both dimensions for `df.loc()`, I suggest you use the argument `header=None` on `pd.read_excel()`.

**Excel File:**

```
    +----+----+----+
    | A  | B  | C  |
+------------------+
|   |    |    |    |
| 1 | hi | hi | hi |
|   |    |    |    |
+------------------+
|   |    |    |    |
| 2 | hi | hi | hi |
|   |    |    |    |
+------------------+
|   |    |    |    |
| 3 | hi | hi | hi |
|   |    |    |    |
+---+----+----+----+
```

**With automatic headers:** (These are strings. You must do `df.loc[0, "hi.0"]`)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('Book1.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
df.head()
```

Output:

```
    +--------------+
    |hi.1|hi.2|hi.3|
+------------------+
|   |    |    |    |
| 0 | hi | hi | hi |
|   |    |    |    |
+------------------+
|   |    |    |    |
| 1 | hi | hi | hi |
|   |    |    |    |
+------------------+
```

**Without headers:** (These are integers. You can safely do `df.loc[0, 2]`)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('Book1.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1', header=None)
df.head()
```

Output:

```
    +----+----+----+
    | 0  | 1  | 2  |
+------------------+
|   |    |    |    |
| 0 | hi | hi | hi |
|   |    |    |    |
+------------------+
|   |    |    |    |
| 1 | hi | hi | hi |
|   |    |    |    |
+------------------+
|   |    |    |    |
| 2 | hi | hi | hi |
|   |    |    |    |
+---+----+----+----+
```

- The reason why I tried to show that difference is, when you said that, *"when I call print(p) after converting p = str(p) it gives me what I want, with the headers in place"*, I am worried about what you mean by 'with headers'. It is supposed to be a string. If you're getting the
  headers in this pattern, then maybe that you're testing the first row only.

Comment: Well, time to go jump off a bridge. Thank you for pointing out the parenthesis, thats probably why Thonny was saying that line did nothing. As for the rest of your answer, I'll give it a read after lunch!

Comment: The method you showed with pandas is what I was trying to do all morning, I pasted your code and made a few tweaks and it does what I wanted it to! I think I'll use xldr as naccode suggested because it seems more like VBA which I'm used to, but thank you for the explanation!